# How to compute the product of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Compute the following product.

$\begin{bmatrix}5&-1&6\\5&3&-6\\-6&2&-9\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}-8\\-4\\-5\end{bmatrix} = ?$

I got:

Row 1: $(5)(-8) + 8 + (-48) = -80$ and it said that was wrong so I didnt even try to do the other two rows. What am I doing wrong? How do I calculate that?

Row 2:

Row 3:

Comment: $5 \times -8 + (-1) \times (-4) + 6 \times (-5) = -40 + 4 - 30 = -66$. What is $6 \times -5$?

Comment: Oh I knew I was doing something wrong lol

Answer (score 2):

Your computation for the first entry was 
$$
5 \times (-8) + (-1) \times (-8) + 6 \times(-8)
$$
which is wrong.  What you should be doing instead is
$$
5 \times (-8) + (-1) \times (-4) + 6 \times(-5)
$$
As a mnemonic: the $i$th row and $j$th column of a matrix product uses (the entire) $i$th row from the first matrix and (the entire) $j$th column from the second matrix. When multiplying a matrix by a column-vector, the entire column gets used for every entry of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Row1: 5*(-8) + (-1)*(-4) + 6*(-5) = -66

Row2: 5*(-8) + 3*(-4) (-6)*(-5) = -22

Row3: -6*(-8) + 2*(-4) + (-9)*(-5) = 85